# Binding to TextBox ReadOnly variable

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class with ReadOnly variable

```
public class Consultant
    {
        private string surname;
        public string Surname
        {
            get { return surname; }
        }
    }
```

Want to binding to Textbox

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=LB, Path=SelectedItem}">
      <TextBox x:Name="TBSurname" Text="{Binding Path=Surname}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I have error when i selected item.
Textbox dont binding to readonly variable

I can change textbox to textblock, but later i need to add inheritance another class who can change Surname
So i need to binding readonly variable to textbox, or maybe something other that correct my problem

I am just learning, and dont understand something maybe, help please

Comment: Did you try to set binding mode to one way?

Comment: one way helps thank you. i can change binding mode later, when Another class will turn?

Answer (score 0):

Your class, `Consultant`, needs to be properly setup for data binding. You should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` class so that the UI is aware of the property and what the value of that property is. Try something like this:

```
public class Consultant : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private string surname;
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  public string Surname
  {
      get { return surname; }
      set 
      {
          surname = value;
          OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Surname));
      }
  }

  private void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
  {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
  }
}
```

Microsoft docs has more on this implementation as well:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: You do not need INPC for binding. If every property is readonly it is totally fine without that notification logic